# How to wait to execute JS until readyState == Complete for document and window?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm going to be blunt. I haven't done HTML/JS coding in years. I'm trying to wait until my window and document are in a completed readyState to add a function to a button externally. I'm struggling. I feel like- no I am a noob at this point.

Does anyone know how to make JS execution wait until the window and document are both in a readyState?

**What I'm trying to do:**

Test the button on my page. I want it to console log "button clicked" when I click it so that I know it is working. I'm using an external file called "setUp.js".

**My html:**

````html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>tbg</title>
        <script src="scripts/setUp/setUp.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/theme.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="staging">
            <p>
              test
            </p>
            <button id="test">
                test
            </button>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>```
````

Comment: Since we don't know the contents of your script the simplest answer is to move your script call to just above the `</body>` tag so that the DOM loads first, and _then_ the script can work on the DOM.

Comment: @Andy I'd like to avoid internal JS for security reasons.

Comment: No. I mean `<script src="scripts/setUp/setUp.js"></script></body>`.